# An equation involving fractional powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I solve: $${ x }^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  }=2$$

I am at the last part of solving an equation of the quadratic type and got stuck here.

Comment: Try cubing both sides first.

Comment: That cleared it up for me. The fractional exponent really threw me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $x^2=2^3=8$, and so $x=\pm\sqrt8$

Comment: Not quite a hint ;)

Answer (score 2):

Raise both sides to the $\frac32$ power. Thus:

$\left(x^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}=\pm 2^{3/2}$

$x^1=\pm 2^{3/2}$

So, the solution is $x=\pm2^{3/2}=\pm2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: shoudn't it be $\pm\sqrt{8}$

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the $\pm$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps
$$ x^{\frac{2}{3}}=\sqrt[3]{\left(x^{2}\right)} =2 $$
$$ x^{2}=2^{3}=8 $$
$$ x=\pm\sqrt{8}=\pm2\sqrt{2}$$